# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to display properly sized splash image in iPhone 5?

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, iphone-5

In our app, the splash screen size is showing the same for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. As a result of this, there are two gaps (one on top and one on bottom) when the app is launched.

How do we go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 as you know Apple changed how the status bar "operates". The status bar *is* part of the app layout by default. This also means it overlaps the splash image at the top.  That's fine.

Also, as you can see when launching a new and unmodified Worklight-based app with an iOS environment in the iOS Simulator or iDevice, the splash image does not produce any "cut lines" at the top and bottom. It displays properly:

[image]

What you need to do is to create a properly sized image of your own **and name it correctly**. The way you name the file is essential - this is how iOS knows how to handle it.

See the Apple Human Interface Guidelines:

- [App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)
- [iOS 7 Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013289)

See a bit more here:

- http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html

For example, for iPhone 5 and above the launch image needs to be 640 x 1136 pixels and it can be titled: `Default-568h@2x~iphone.png` and you place it in your-app\iphone\native\Resources:

[image]